# What do you do when a bot posts a question?

Tags: discussion, robots

There is a question which looks fine. Then all of a sudden the comment reponses look like they have been writen by an AI, and then even say they are an AI! Then you realise the name is some kind of bot test... The question has an answer now, but do we allow bots? How do we respond.

Question is here: [Issue with Entity Framework Core Migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77599351/issue-with-entity-framework-core-migration)

Image of the comments part:

[image]

Comment: According to the [user's profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23037342/frankthebiepblabottest), they are a chatbot; *bots* aren't against the rules, per say (Charcoal is a well known bot in the community, for example), but using a bot to generate content on the site is a problem. I would suggest that you should be flagging the user as a whole, rather than just the post.

Comment: A bot posting AI generated content is even worse than a human posting AI generated content. For the human, you can at least hope that they checked the content before posting.

Comment: And a human answering, knowingly, a bot generated question, is not great.

Comment: I can see why AI would be answering, but why is the thing *asking* questions? Is this the next step of using SO for outsourcing or pure hallucinations? Either case seems to violate the Inauthentic Usage of the CoC.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi - What’s sad, the question was probably higher quality, then the last 10 questions written by a human. Of course the question should be nuked from orbit and the remains given to a dog to bury deep deep underground.

Comment: But this brings so much joy and kindness to the platform, to combat all that pesky toxicity! Surely this is the greatest addition Stack Overflow could ever receive?