# Tricky review audit of a bot-generated First Question

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits

There is an audit review in the First Question Queue: [35377416](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/35377416).

The question is best described by the quote from a Meta [discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427396/21350362):

> There is a question which looks fine. Then all of a sudden the comment responses look like they have been written by an AI, and then even say they are an AI!

Yet all these first-class markers are not present in the audit: neither the username (...BlaBotTest), nor the comments.

Could be that the question looked good right until those comments appeared?

On the one hand, this audit actually helped and boosted my intention to skip. On the other hand, it doesn't look like mandatory inspection of meta links (for new questions?!) in comments is a good use case for an audit.

### UPD #1:

I started doubting myself, if I actually saw that comment with a link to meta during the review. It might be that I didn’t. Later I got another audit: [35381148](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/35381148). You can see three comments there. But there were none during the actual review! So I presume that both username, rating, date asked, votes, number of answers, views and also comments presented in an audit review – all have a stochastic nature. That means that there could be future reviewers who’ll see the only okayish looking question with both actions Edit (AFAIK) and Looks OK resulting in a failure. I have no data to go any further, so I’m humbly asking moderators to check on the questioned audit some time later, if it shows statistically significant lower passing rate. Or pin those GPTish comments in the audit if it’s possible.

Comment: Generally the *better* thing to do is to open the question *outside* of the review queue; context is king and the review queue rarely gives all of it. If you did, then you'd have got a 404 error, and then known the question was an audit.

Comment: @Thom A, yep, it looks like a good way to go. Suspicious of an audit – just click on it. Thanks. Yet I’m a bit anxious about the _Generally_ part. It’s my second week reviewing and I’m still looking for how much effort I should put into these tasks. My basis is that a reviewer should not be able to distinguish an audit from a regular review. And should follow similar patterns regardless. And I’m struggling to accept that one should open the question he or she was going to accept…

Comment: moderately related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/422338/11107541

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- This post (to me, at least) shows a score of -11 and is closed (not to mention it has a purely text-based error message formatted as code instead of as a block quote... eurgh).
- Furthermore, when you click on the title to open the post in a new tab or window, you'll see either that the question is deleted, or a 404 page (depending on your reputation).

The first bullet point conditions should prime you for "this is either a bad post, or a review audit", the latter half of which should prompt you to follow the step in the second bullet point: check the post directly (outside of the review queue) to determine whether it's an audit or a truly bad post.

In either case, you should only choose "Looks OK" in the review queue for this item if, when you go to the post directly, it isn't closed and doesn't have a massively negative score.

That there is a discussion about whether the post was generated by a bot account or not is irrelevant to whether the post is in the LQP queue as a genuine item or an audit.

Comment: But you cannot see -11 or the closed status in the audit?

Comment: @WeijunZhou I can't tell what OP saw, but when I click the link I see that it was an audit and that it's closed and at -11 score.

Comment: I do believe that OP cannot see the closed status or the -11 score when he's doing the audit (w/o opening in a new tab of course), so I think the first bullet can be better phrased.

Comment: As an audit the score wouldn’t be shown. However, trying to expand the comment section, likely would have still failed. The question honestly was very low quality. This is an example of an audit question that serves its purpose making sure your paying attention

Comment: Indeed. If the first bullet mentions the obvious giveaway from the comments, it would be a better answer.

Comment: Yep, making a habit of opening suspicious items solves the problem, thanks. Few notes though. It was the First questions queue, not the Low quality one. Scores in an audit are usually mocked to zero. I updated the question with notes that comments could also be randomly filtered. Plus my bias that day was shaken by my quoted error message edit being undone presumably during a review. Btw doesn’t Editing also lead to a failure on such audits?